# Interaction between 'Exporter', 'use vars', and 'local'

Tags: perl, scope

I have tried to boil this behavior down to the simplest test case.  Consider the following two modules:

#### Bar.pm

```
package Bar;

use base 'Exporter';
use vars qw/ $BarVar /;
BEGIN { @EXPORT_OK = qw/ $BarVar /; }

$BarVar = 'original';

1;
```

#### Foo.pm

```
package Foo;

use Bar qw/ $BarVar /;

sub foo { print $BarVar . "\n"}

1;
```

Now, the output of the following script -

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Foo;

{
  local $Bar::BarVar = 'modified'; 
  Foo::foo();
}

Foo::foo();
```

is "original" printed twice, where I would have expected it to be "modified" followed by "original", because I would have expected the `local` declaration to replace the package variable `$Bar::BarVar` throughout its whole scope, which includes the first call to `foo()`.  What's the explanation?  How can I locally override `$Bar::BarVar`?

Comment: Try `print \$Foo::BarVar, \$Bar::BarVar;` before and after the `local`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have heard me say that `my` and `our` create variables (the latter of which is aliased), but that `local` just makes a temporary backup of the value.

I lied.

`local` does make a backup, but not of the value. It backs up the address of the associated scalar, creates a new scalar, and associates the name with the new scalar. In this case, that leaves `$Bar::BarVar` referring to the new scalar, and `$Foo::BarVar` referring to the old scalar.

```
$ perl -E'
   *x = \$y;  say \$x, " - ", \$y;
   local $y;  say \$x, " - ", \$y;
'
SCALAR(0x44d7c70) - SCALAR(0x44d7c70)
SCALAR(0x44d7c70) - SCALAR(0x44ba130)
```

If you were to actually backup just the value, the problem would go away.

```
use Sub::ScopeFinalizer qw( scope_finalizer );

{
   my $backup = $Bar::BarVar;
   my $guard = scope_finalizer { $Bar::BarVar = $backup };
   $Bar::BarVar = 'modified'; 
   Foo::foo();
}
```

A more specialized tool might exist.

Answer (score 1):

See [What Not to Export](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#What-Not-to-Export):

> There's one more item to add to this list. Do not export variable names. Just because Exporter lets you do that, it does not mean you should.
>
> ```
>  @EXPORT_OK = qw($svar @avar %hvar); # DON'T!
> ```
>
> Exporting variables is not a good idea. They can change under the hood, provoking horrible effects at-a-distance that are too hard to track and to fix. Trust me: they are not worth it.
>
> To provide the capability to set/get class-wide settings, it is best instead to provide accessors as subroutines or class methods instead.

There is one exception this rule: If you have constant variables (such those created using [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast)), you can export them because, by definition, they can't create effects at a distance.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm working with some legacy code here :)